# Reading Task on SerialDevice on Windows Iot Core

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi3, uart, windows-10-iot-core

I'm attempting to write a `Task` which will run until cancelled which will read any data which has been received by the UART and proceed to dispatch the received data through a defined `event`. I want the read loop to read for 200 ms before returning with any data it may have read in that timeslice (including possibly zero data) or when a full buffer has been read, whichever occurs first; the vast majority of the time the timeout will occur first. I have successfully sent data out the UART but I have failed to receive any data even though it has been confirmed the device received the data on the wire.

```
SerialDevice device;

// Instantiate the SerialDevice.

device.ReadTimeout = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 0, 200 );
ReadDataCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

const uint BufferSize_bytes = 50;

ReadDataTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( async () =>
{
    using( DataReader reader = new DataReader( device.InputStream ) )
    {
       reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

       while( !ReadDataCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested )
       {
          uint dataRead = await reader.LoadAsync( BufferSize_bytes ).AsTask();

          if( dataRead > 0 )
          {
             IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer( dataRead );
             if( buffer.Length > 0 )
                PropogateReceivedData( ReadBuffer( buffer ) );
          }
       }
    }
}, ReadDataCancellationTokenSource.Token );
```

The `PropogateReceivedData( ReadBuffer( buffer ) )` call reads all the data in the buffer and then the data is dispatched; this is known to be working correctly. The `ReadDataCancellationTokenSource` member is stored to shutdown the `Task` when needed.

Given the challenges I have experienced trying to get this approach, I am wondering if it should work or if not, what I need to do to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have successfully sent data out the UART but I have failed to
>   receive any data even though it has been confirmed the device received
>   the data on the wire.

I am not sure how you "confirmed the device received the data on the wire". As you set `InputStreamOptions.Partial` so even if there is only one byte on the wire this line `await reader.LoadAsync( BufferSize_bytes ).AsTask();` will return you will get this one byte in the buffer.

Also I've no idea how do you handle the received data in `PropogateReceivedData( ReadBuffer( buffer ) )`, here I use the follow lines converting the data to string and display in UI you can refer to:

```
                                var dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
                                rcvdText.Text = dataReader.ReadString(buffer.Length);
```

My suggestion is you can use `reader.ReadString(dataRead);` if you want get string data and use `reader.ReadBytes(readData);` if you want get bytes stream. More supported APIs you can refer to [DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader#methods).

> Given the challenges I have experienced trying to get this approach, I
>   am wondering if it should work or if not, what I need to do to get it
>   to work.

Yes, your logic should work, except for me the read timeout never occurs. Can you confirm the read timeout works for you as you set `device.ReadTimeout = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 0, 200 );`? Is there any timeout information?

The following is the whole code lines I get from your question to test, it works for me.

```
                device.ReadTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
                var ReadDataCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                const uint BufferSize_bytes = 50;

                using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(device.InputStream))
                {
                    reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

                    while (!ReadDataCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        uint dataRead = await reader.LoadAsync(BufferSize_bytes).AsTask();

                        if (dataRead > 0)
                        {
                            IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer(dataRead);
                            if (buffer.Length > 0)
                            {
                                //    rcvdText.Text = reader.ReadString(dataRead);

                                //    var readData = new Byte[dataRead];
                                //    reader.ReadBytes(readData);

                                var dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
                                rcvdText.Text = dataReader.ReadString(buffer.Length);
                                status.Text = "bytes read successfully!";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

[Official serial sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/SerialUART) you can refer to.

Comment: For completeness, the physical data transmission was confirmed as received by oscilloscope reading. I did get the reading to work using the above code (as there was a hardware error in the system) but I have not received time-out information.